# Access files in production-mode of django project

Tags: python, django

For my Django project I have to open an xsl-file that is permanently located on the server to perform some actions on other files that the users can upload. In development mode I just used a relative path in the python script to point to that xsl-file and it worked fine:

```
xslFile = open('./transform.xsl')
```

However, as I am now in the stage of deploying the project to the server, I am having troubles with changing that line of code so that the file can still be found in production mode.
I already tried setting an absolute path like

```
xslFile = open('/srv/www/htdocs/djangoProject/mysite/transform.xsl')
```

which threw errors. Furthermore I tried moving the file to the static directory which I state in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

and tried then to open the file like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
xslFile = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'transform.xsl'))
```

However, both of these tries produce error messages of this kind:

> **FileNotFoundError at /mysite/add/**
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transform.xsl'
>
> Request Method:   POST Request
>
> URL:  xx.xx.xx.xxx/mysite/add/ Django Version:    2.2.7 Exception
>
> Type: FileNotFoundError Exception Value:   [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: 'transform.xsl' Exception
>
> Location: /srv/www/htdocs/djangoProject/mysite/createDatabase.py in
> handleInputFiles, line 84 Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3 Python
> Version:  3.6.5

The django application is accessed by an Apache2 installation using the wsgi.py interface.

What is the right way to access the xsl-file?

Comment: maybe you have a typo your file is **xls**, not **xsl**

Comment: DANGER - Friendly warning here: I don't know what is in that file, but please remember that (generally speaking) everything in /static is assumed to be safe to show the public in its entirety. In other words, if I go to http :// diamon.com/static/transform.xsl are you ok that I can see that file? Putting files in your /static/ just so your web process can find them shows a misunderstanding and is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your file ends with ***.xsl**?
maybe a typo **.xls**

in `settings.py` you have default base dir. This is the base of your project.
If you place the xls in media/myxls.xls

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

in your `views.py`

```
from myproject.settings import BASE_DIR
import os

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/myxls.xls') as file:
    print(myfile.read())
```

if you access a file that way, you dont need to use the absolute path, and it's flexible.

When you put the file in the static folder, did you run `./manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: You are right! I seem to have produced some typo somewhere. After frantically tiping all solutions again it works now by manually putting the files to the static directory and creating the link in the python script like described in my question (from django.conf import settings
xslFile = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'transform.xsl'))). I am terribly sorry for wasting time on this issue, but your answer made me notice my typo, so thanks a lot :)